# I getting trouble when i am creating this type play store app icon anyone can help me

Tags: image, google-play, playback, image-editing, image-effects

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3EyC.png)

how can I turn the image right side without photoshop please help me!!

Comment: Do you mean size (not side)?

Comment: it is side when I created that type of image left and right image was straight  but above image is bend in

Answer (score 0):

I have converted your logo to meet your specifications here : https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9866151?hl=en-GB#zippy=%2Chigh-res-icon

This is the logo that should be uploaded successfully to the Google Play Store (32-bit PNG 512 x 512) and have been made not to get cropped by Google Play:

[image]

Comment: I mean create another logo like that

Comment: Try the one that is attached, I have made it to fit the guidelines. I added borders so it is not cropped by google play.

Comment: which tool you use to create